# Portable shebang line for Julia with command-line options?

Tags: julia

I'm writing "scripts" in Julia, that I use from the command line. For example:

```julia
#!/usr/bin/env julia

@info "Hello world!"
```

Using a shebang line like this makes it possible to make such a script executable and easily run it without explicitly invoking julia:

```
$ ./hello
[ Info: Hello world!
```

However, passing additional command-line arguments to julia in such a shebang line is not portable (at least does not work for Linux, which I care about). Is there a way to overcome this limitation? For example, how could I make sure that my script will be run with `julia -O0 --compile=min`?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to do this is documented in the [FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-pass-options-to-julia-using-#!/usr/bin/env?). Adapting the example to your case:

```julia
#!/bin/bash
#=
exec julia -O0 --compile=min "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@"
=#

@info "Hello world!"
```